# Exception when opening new libgdx project in intellij

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to learn Libgdx and I used the project creator to create a project with the default settings. I then try to open the build.gradle in the root of the project and I keep getting an exception. Anyone know what is causing this and how I can open the project?

Intellij 2018.1.4

> java.lang.NullPointerException at com.android.tools.idea.project.messages.AbstractSyncMessages.removeMessages(AbstractSyncMessages.java:79) at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.messages.GradleSyncMessages.removeProjectMessages(GradleSyncMessages.java:50) at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.notification.GradleNotificationExtension.customize(GradleNotificationExtension.java:57) at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.notification.ExternalSystemNotificationManager.createNotification(ExternalSystemNotificationManager.java:168) at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil.createFailureResult(ExternalSystemUtil.java:651) at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$3.onFailure(ExternalSystemUtil.java:517) at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.ExternalSystemProgressNotificationManagerImpl.onFailure(ExternalSystemProgressNotificationManagerImpl.java:124) at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:94) at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:163) at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:149) at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:542) at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:605) at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:750) at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:434) at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157) at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580) at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525) at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85) at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144) at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$null$10(ApplicationImpl.java:565) at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:305) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Well I have no idea what happened. I went and had lunch and tried it again and it worked!